# In the TEST_DB create the following views using data from AdventureWorks2012:

Tags: sql, sql-server

A view with full names, shipping address, billing address and total due for each customer who has done an order. List each customer with their individual orders

=>

```
go
create view employ as

        select employee.BusinessEntityID,
           firstname + ' ' +isnull( middlename + ' ','') +lastname as 'fullname',
           shippingaddress, billingaddress, totaldue, customer, individualorder    
        from AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee
   inner join AdventureWorks2012.person.person on employee.businessentityid = person.businessentityid
   inner join AdventureWorks2012.person.Address on employee.businessentityid = Address.AddressID
   inner join AdventureWorks2012.sales.SalesOrderDetail on employee.businessentityid = SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
   inner join AdventureWorks2012.sales.Customer on employee.businessentityid = customer.CustomerID
GO

-- Now select from the view
Select * From employ
```

NOTE : I have edited my query but still got invalid columns for shipping address, billing address, total due and  customer. Do i need a customer column?Can some one please update by adding or deleting unnecessary to my query in order to correct it. so I understand the logic.

Comment: Looks like homework to me. Post your errors.

Comment: This `employ.businessentityid` doesn't look right.

Comment: Is inner join AdventureWorks2012.person.Person and inner join AdventureWorks2012.person.person the same table which you have changed the case? seems only one would be necessary

Comment: it is for my understanding.

Comment: Error message:  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure employee, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: @WEI_DBA ,can you clarify me what you saying. thanks

Comment: The alias `employ` doesn't exist. I believe you want `employee` instead. Also, remove the second `inner join` as @scsimon says. That's a duplicate. Finally, remove the last `Select` statement, that's giving you the error.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i want employee. would you please explain with your own code so i can understand clear.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation above, I believe you can fix this with:

If you want to query the view, create it first then `Select * From employ`

```
    create view employ as

        select employee.BusinessEntityID,
           firstname + ' ' +isnull( middlename + ' ','') +lastname as 'fullname',
           shippingaddress, billingaddress, totaldue, customer, individualorder    
        from AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee
        inner join AdventureWorks2012.person.person 
                   on employee.businessentityid = person.businessentityid

GO

-- Now select from the view
Select * From employ
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @WEI_DBA. I execute the code. it identify the full  but invalid column name for  shipping address, billingaddress, totaldue,customer,individualorder. how do i link them.

Comment: Post the table schemas. That will show you the real column names.